# How to make Storybook addon 'addon-links' work for Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, storybook

I am trying to learn how to use Storybook for my project that uses Vue.js and i can't seem to make the addon 'addon-links' to work since the documentation is mostly in React.

I installed

```
npm i --save @storybook/vue
npm i --save vue-loader@13.6.1
npm i --save @storybook/addon-actions
npm i --save @storybook/addon-links
```

The addon 'addon-actions' works.

For 'addon-links' I used various examples on the net, here is one of them .

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue'

import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links'

...

storiesOf('Button', module)
  .add('First', () => ({
    template: `<button @click="action">Go to "Second"</button>`,
    methods: {
      action: () => {
        console.log('Go to "Second"')
        linkTo('Button', 'Second')
      }
    }
  }))
  .add('Second', () => ({
    template: `<button @click="action">Go to "First"</button>`,
    methods: {
      action: () => {
        console.log('Go to "First"')
        linkTo('Button', 'First')
      }
    }
  }))
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.0.22",
    "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^3.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.3.5",
    "vform": "^0.8.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.3.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.6.1",
    "vue-meta": "^1.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.3.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.3.11",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^3.3.11",
    "@storybook/vue": "^3.3.11",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue-libs": "^2.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.7.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

The `console.log` works. The Storybook UI works and the button generates the event but it does not change to the next story using `linkto`.

Can anyone help me whit this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing ***without*** the `getstorybook` command, the linked buttons work for me with

```
methods: {
  action: linkTo('Button', 'Second') 
}
```

and this works

```
methods: {
  action: linkTo('Button', (e) => {
    console.log('Go to "Second"')
    return 'Second';
  }) 
}
```

but not this

```
methods: {
  action: () => {
    console.log('Go to "Second"')
    linkTo('Button', 'Second')
  }
}
```

**Installing**
from [Storybook for Vue](https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-vue/),

- npm i --save-dev @storybook/vue
- npm i --save vue
- npm i --save-dev babel-core

from this question

- npm i --save vue-loader@13.6.1
- npm i --save-dev @storybook/addon-actions
- npm i --save-dev @storybook/addon-links

after some compilation errors

- npm i --save-dev vue-template-compiler
- npm i --save vuex

This is my **.storybook/addons.js**

```js
import '@storybook/addon-actions/register'
import '@storybook/addon-links/register'
```

This is my **.storybook/config.js**

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue'

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'; // Vue plugins

function loadStories() {
  require('../src/stories')
}

configure(loadStories, module)
```

This is my **src/stories/index.js**

```js
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links';

storiesOf('Button', module)
  .add('First', () => ({
    template: `<button @click="action">Go to "Second"</button>`,
    methods: {
      action: linkTo('Button', 'Second') 
    }
  }))
  .add('Second', () => ({
    template: `<button @click="action">Go to "First"</button>`,
    methods: { 
      action: linkTo('Button', 'First') 
    }
  }))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the example I am using there are no other components, just a simple HTML button, so there is no need for the `components: { MyButton }`. I tried it anyway just to be absolutely sure but it did not work. The addon, in the examples I've seen, seems to work for pure Vue.js so React.js should not be needed. I tried other functions/methods syntax and that didn't work either. Any ideas of other possible problems?

Comment: Actually, my first and second buttons work ok without the `components` attribute. I assumed it was needed because the examples (first 3 buttons above) show it. I totally missed the fact that `<button>` is not the selector for  the `MyButton` component.

Comment: The only other factor that seems relevant is the method of installing Storybook.

Comment: I managed to make work the following addons: `Actions` ,  `Knobs` ,  `Notes` ,  `Console`  all with similar installing. The only one that just does not work is the `Links` addon.

Comment: If I follow your install, I can't get storyboard to compile. Have you left out some steps?

Comment: `npm i --save vue`
`npm i --save-dev babel-core` after `npm i --save-dev @storybook/vue`

Comment: There were a few - initially related to missing installs, the last message was quite obscure. I started with a vue-cli project, so now I'm doing over, proceeding strictly as per your steps.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Component Story Format (CSF) I have found a way to do what you are asking.

```js
    export const myStory = () => ({
      components: { MyComponent },
      template: `<div style="width: 640px">
        <my-component :my-data="myData" @updated="updated" />
      </div>`,
      data() {
        return {
          myData: null,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        action: action('data-updated'),            // define the raw action
        updated($event) {
          this.myData = $event;                 // alter your data locally
          this.action($event);                      // call the raw action using a method
        }
      }
    });
```

It took a fair bit of fiddling - but that is how I did it.